# Where does BibDesk store temporary files?

Tags: bibdesk

I was updating a bib file using BibDesk, when the app crashed. I had not saved the file in hours. Did I just waste my morning, or does BibDesk save a temporary file somewhere while working on a bibliography, sort of like Office apps do?

I failed to locate such a file (Googling did not help), so I killed BibDesk hoping that a crash recovery wizard would come up at restart... but *of course* not, there is nothing like that.

Comment: I guess this depends on the OS you're running.

Comment: usually in `~\Library\Application Support`. you can get there by Terminal or `Go to folder`

Comment: Have you tried to re-open the file? What OS version are you using? Unless you disabled it you may be able to recover the work since the OS auto-saves files.

Comment: I was using Mac OS X (El Capitan), I had already checked that Library folder, and the file was not auto-saved, unfortunately. But thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have enabled the option to "Automatically save a backup document every *n* minutes" in BibDesk's "Opening and Saving" preference pane (accessed via the menu item *BibDesk > Preferences...*), then BibDesk will automatically save a backup copy of any changed open `bib` file every *n* minutes (where *n* >= 5) in the same folder as the open file with "(Autosaved)" appended to the filename.

If you have not enabled this option, then it would be a good idea to save open `bib` files after every change, to avoid losing work in case the app crashes, because unsaved changes are held in RAM.